# Laravel only return Child (relationships) not Parent

Tags: php, laravel

The Models I am working with are One-to-Many with this structure:

```
User->Distributors->Accounts->Notes
```

Where A `User` has many `Distributors` that has many `Accounts` that has many `Notes`.

If I want to get all the `User` `Notes` I need to follow down the chain to make sure I only get the notes belonging to that user.

My current model does that but returns more info (the distributors) than needed. It would be nice to only return the `Notes` and the `Account` it belongs to, no need to get the `Distributor` as well.

Controller:

```
public function showManager($id)
    {
        $user           = User::find($id);
        $distributors   = User::find($id)->distributorsWithAccounts;
        $notes          = User::find($id)->notes;

        //dd($notes);

        return view('admin/managers-single',
        [ 
            'user'          => $user,
            'distributors'  => $distributors,
            'notes'         => $notes,
        ]);
    }
```

User Model:

```
public function notes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Distributor')->with('accountsWithNotes');
    }
```

Dist Model:

```
public function accountsWithNotes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Account')->has('notes')->with('notes');
    }
```

Account Model:

```
public function notes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Note');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel actually has a `hasManyThrough` query just for this. So I changed my `User Model function` to look like so:

```
public function notes()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Account', 'App\Distributor')->has('Notes')->with('Notes');
    }
```

THis now just dumps the `Accounts` that have `Notes` with their info as well

Answer (score 0):

You can have all that data in just one query my friend like this
`User::whereId($id)->with('distributors.notes')` I don't know how are you models related at all but I'll put an example I have my models user, roles and permissions in my user model i have a method called role and in the role method a function called permissions.

I can call them with a query `User::whereId($id)->with('role.permissions')` and the answer will be something like `{user_propertes...., role:{role_properties..., permissions:[{},{},{},{}]}}`